# Trigger button when finger drag crossed it

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to trigger a button when I drag my finger across, instead of pressing it directly. I have tried all the events associated with buttons and none worked in any combination. I have also tried the tap gesture, swipe gesture, and the pan gesture. These didn't trigger the button when I pressed off the button and drag crossed it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 49, width: 568, height: 8))
    button.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
}
```

or

```
@IBAction func s2(sender: AnyObject) {

print("1")    

}
```

Comment: Add a gesture recognizer to the `UIButton`. Add the code you've tried to your question.

Comment: You'll get events in the view where the finger first comes down, so you'll need probably a transparent view over everything that has a pan gesture recognizer associated with it or just use raw touch event handling, then you need to track the coordinates of the view and map them into the coordinates of your `UIButton` to detect when a drag-over happens.

Comment: I also tried the storyboard method with pan gesture and it made me click the button on the inside and no matter where it was whenever I dragged the mouse it pressed the button

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your button.

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doSomething))
button.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

func doSomething() {
    //do something here
}
```